# Can you connect to LAN worlds with the same IP address as you?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

I've been wanting to know if you can connect to LAN worlds with the same IP address as you. My brother wants to get another minecraft account so we can play together on the same world but we both have the same IP address. Is it possible to connect to the same LAN world if we both have the same IP address?

Comment: If you liked the answer you can upvote it to help other users.

Comment: You should read about [private networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network); your answer isn't really about Minecraft so much as how they work.

Answer (score -16, accepted):

No you need different Ip addresses in order to play on a LAN world. So you need 2 different computers. You don't have the same IP address. An IP address is a fingerprint of a computer. No 2 are alike. You can find your Ip at whatsmyIp.com.

Comment: Well, they likely have the same external IP address if they are on the same LAN (whatsmyip.com will show the same IP on both computers) but they will have different LAN ip's visible from `ipconfig` from the command line.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yup that is entirely true.

Comment: This is wrong in a few ways. a) Two computers can have the same IP address. When it's on the same network that's called an IP conflict or collision; when on different networks that's called "normal". b) They're not like fingerprints at all. More like house addresses. MAC is like a fingerprint. c) At the same time you say that they won't have the same IP address and then you say they can see that they're different by using whatsmyip.com, which will actually show them that they have the *same* IP address because that reports external IP address, not local IP address. In conclusion: -1.

Comment: It turns out, unless my computer is really weird, this is not true! Which excites me a lot more than I'd like to admit.

Answer (score 8):

### You'll be able to play just fine!

You are probably looking at your external IP address, which is actually the IP address that your *router* uses to connect you to Internet at large. That's shared by all the computers on your home network, but *only* for the purpose of accessing the Internet and that IP address has nothing to do with playing LAN games.

On your home network (probably wifi, right?) you have a completely *separate* collection of IP addresses just for your computers' local networking use, and each computer gets an unique address from that collection. (Your router tries very hard to makes sure one computer never has the same IP address as another computer. It's possible, but close to impossible to happen unless someone has been seriously messing with the router's configuration.)

So, you have different addresses, which makes everything fine. As a bonus, you don't even need to care about IP addresses to play Minecraft over LAN, because it will autodetect worlds that have been opened to LAN and just let you click-and-play.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out, **no**, a separate IP address is *not* required. As is the norm with my answers, I can back this up with some ***SCIENCE***.

I opened up two instances of Minecraft. On the first, I opened up a world to LAN. On the second, I opened up the multiplayer menu. And to my surprise and delight, it showed up! However, when I tried to log in, it gave me this message:

[image: Disconnected by Server: That name is already taken.]

So **no**, you do not need two separate IP addresses, or even two separate computers. You just need to be connected to the same local network, and also have two separate Minecraft accounts.

Comment: I will look into the possibility of doing it with only one account, but it will likely require some command line magic, or something of that nature. Not certain if it's possible with the new launcher, though.

Comment: I can confirm that you can connect two instances of Minecraft running on the same computer, so long as you have two different Minecraft names. (Command line magic works, but takes a bit of magicking to pull off. Two real accounts is simpler.) That has to do with using different ports for the same IP: the server snags `25565` as an incoming port, but the client uses a somewhat-random outgoing port to connect. So, under the hood, this setup looks something like `localhost:87667 connecting to localhost:25565 ... success!`

Comment: @SevenSidedDie That may or may not explain why the IP showed up as my actual IP address (which is why I didn't post that screenshot), rather than `127.0.0.1` then.

Answer (score 0):

You can make fool the system by applying same IP address as well as the MAC address of your adapter.
After setting these two parameters, there will not be IP conflict and you can do your task.

Answer (score -1):

My two daughters are playing Minecraft, they want to play on the same world, but they can't as the server they are trying to play on only allows one player per IP. As the world will only ever see the external IP given to us from the provider, they as result cannot play on the same world.

The only way to do that would be to somehow trick the world into seeing one of their computers with another IP. I haven't tried it yet, but maybe some sort of proxy setting.

Comment: This has nothing to do with LAN worlds.